# Copying MySQL Database via FTP (FileZilla, Ubuntu, Zabbix)

Tags: ubuntu, backup, mysql, ftp, zabbix

I have recently discovered that we are not backing up our Zabbix database and i was wondering if it is possible to take a backup via FTP on FileZilla by essentially copying the files from the mysql directory?

In the long term we will have a script to handle this properly but i want to make sure we can get a backup done ASAP in case anything goes wrong! (this will be the quickest way for it to be done i believe but i am not too familiar with Ubuntu and Zabbix...)

The reason for the back up via FTP is so that the backup is not stored on the server, i would like to move it elsewhere

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to back a MySQL database up by copying the `mysql` directory, *if you stop MySQL* first. A better solution is to use a backup tool which knows how to deal with MySQL; I use `automysqlbackup` which is [available in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/automysqlbackup). After some simple configuration (or even none, if you’re using the MySQL packages in their default configuration), it will produce backups of your database at regular intervals (daily, weekly, and monthly), and it will keep a varying amount of each. You can then copy the backups elsewhere if necessary.

Comment: This is a good article to help configure, it is very quick and easy to set up: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-do-painless-mysql-server-backups-automysqlbackup

Comment: It’s even easier than that using the package in Debian or Ubuntu — the package is setup correctly by default (for a default MySQL installation), and all the configuration settings are in `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`. Actually following the linked article’s advice would break the package :-(.